# Problems updating MySQL, "username" in a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm probably not using the best method to create a user system, but it doesn't need to be fancy. I also know that I'm not the most organized

The logins and everything are alright, but I'm having a problem updating the credentials.

For example, I'm allowing users to change their username. I have the "Change Username" (Not that name) form to submit to update-username.php.

**I already have mysql_real_escape_string, in the function "cleanString" in another page. My textarea submitting already has the old text in it, so you can change and view it before hand.**

```
$user_id = "";
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $user_id = $_POST['id'];    
}

$query = "SELECT username,email,display_name,access,password FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$results = mysql_query($query);

if(!$results) { //Check to see if query failed
die(mysql_error());
}

$resultsfetch=mysql_fetch_array($results);
$username = $resultsfetch['username'];
$usernamenew = $_POST['usernameinput'];
if(isset($_POST['usernameinput'])) {
    $usernamenew = cleanString($_POST['usernameinput']);
}

if($usernamenew !=$username){
    $submit = "UPDATE users SET username = '$usernamenew' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
    mysql_query($submit);
    if(!$submit) { //Check to see if query failed
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

It's probably something stupid or simple that I missed, or something really huge. Mainly because I am absent minded.

Comment: Where does `$user_id` come from? Why you check for POST being set after you assign it? What does `cleanString()` do? If `$user_id` is an int, you shoulnd't quote it. Your last check (`if(!$submit)`) won't ever work since `$submit` is the string, so it's always set; you might want to check the return of `mysql_query($submit)` instead. Anyway, what happens? errors, data not being changed, ...?

Comment: Not solution to the problem but `$usernamenew = $_POST['usernameinput'];` should be `$usernamenew = $resultsfetch['username'];`. or you will get warning if `$_POST['usernameinput']` is not set.

Comment: @bansi Agree on the possible error, but I think $usernamennew should be the posted username, to be compared with the old in DB

Comment: I had forgotten to include where the variable comes from. I have updated the post. The page just continues as usual, not updating the database.

Comment: You should use `mysql_real_escape_string` if using this. Imagine `$_POST['id'] = "' or '1' = '1"`. Now your SQL is `UPDATE users SET username = '$usernamenew' WHERE user_id = '' or '1' = '1'`. And all usernames are changed to same. Or maybe typecast to int `$user_id = (int)$_POST['id'];`

Comment: @DamienPirsy, OP is comparing `if($usernamenew !=$username){` so if nothing is posted it should be the data from the DB.

Comment: if `$user_id = ""` then you should not execute all the fetch..update as you are not going to get any row in `$resultsfetch=mysql_fetch_array($results);`

Comment: I already have mysql_real_escape_string, in the function "cleanString" in another variable. My text area submitting already has the old text in it, so you can change and view it before hand.

My issue is it's not updating.

Answer (score 0):

```
$submit = sprintf("UPDATE users SET username = '%s' WHERE user_id = %d",mysql_real_escape_string($usernamenew),mysql_real_escape_string($user_id));
```

Comment: Using `mysql_real_scape_STRING()` on an int? Why not typecasting it instead?

Answer (score 0):

If the page is loaded, `$user_id` will be `NULL` so noting will be updated! Make sure that this page loads, by sending `$_POST['id']` . if these things are correct, check this.

"Did the database user have any permission to update the table? "

Answer (score 0):

I have re-arranged your code. added comments where i changed. Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['usernameinput'])) { // Check if both POST id and usernameinput is available
    $user_id = (int)$_POST['id']; //assuming this is an integer

    $query = "SELECT username,email,display_name,access,password FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    $results = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$results) {//Check to see if query failed
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { //verify if there is really a user with such id
        $resultsfetch = mysql_fetch_array($results);
        $username = $resultsfetch['username'];
        $usernamenew = cleanString($_POST['usernameinput']);

        if ($usernamenew != $username) {
            $submit = "UPDATE users SET username = '$usernamenew' WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
            if (!mysql_query($submit)) {//Check to see if query failed
                die(mysql_error());
            }
        }

    }else{
        die("no such user with userid=$user_id");
    }
}
```

**Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: You should not quote ints...Also, as I said in the other comment, `$submit` is the QUERY, the string, so `if(!$submit)` doesn't make sense. You should check `if(!mysql_query($submit))`

Comment: @DamienPirsy thanks for pointing out the the error, fixed it. Also it is not required but valid to quote ints in query (trying to keep edits to minimum lines).

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess I figured it out. It's an issue with my code carrying over to the next page.

The code I had been shown only broke the page, whether it be missing an integer, or something else. I'm not 100% sure.

Thanks for all the help guys, but now I know the issue.

EDIT:
I had forgotten to `echo` the `$user_id` in my hidden field.

Comment: So post the right answer and accept it, or delete the question altogether since the answer has nothing to do with it. This post you wrote isn't an answer.